# Difference between gLite and OpenNebula

Tags: grid, cloud, grid-computing, opennebula

What is the difference between gLite and OpenNebula?
I intend to differences in structure and in usage. When to use the one and when the other?

Answer (score 0):

I think g.lite is a DSL service that offers a download speed that is slower than other forms (maximum of 1.5 Mbps).
Whereas, OpenNebula is a cloud computing toolkit for managing heterogeneous or different distributed database center infrastructures.

Answer (score 0):

gLite is a grid middleware, which -- very simply put -- takes care of (bulk) submission and processing of grid jobs (+ related tasks like scheduling, data handling, monitoring, information service and others).

OpenNebula is a cloud management framework, which -- again put simply -- provides you with virtual machines on demand, based on available templates.

So, you will use gLite if your workload comes in the form of jobs (think scripts), which can run in the target system (gLite is currently only supported in Debian 6 and Scinetific Linux 5 & 6). You will use OpenNebula if you need on-demand virtual machines running your own (or publically available vanilla) system images. You can of course preinstall any software you need in those images.)

I promise to give a better aimed answer if you say more about what your situation is and what you want to achieve. Both products are actually intended to  provide different kind of service.